# nginx - DNS works for www. but not for http://

Tags: nginx, dns

I have a server that is using ngnix and I have a configuration file:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name http://mycoolwebsite.com/;
   return 301 http://www.mycoolwebsite.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/website/front/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name  www.mycoolwebsite.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Now when I enter `http://www.mycoolwebsite.com` the website shows just fine. Whenever I enter `http://mycoolwebsite.com` I get:

> > This site can’t be reached | server DNS address could not be found.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server name in the first server block should be:

```
server_name mycoolwebsite.com;
```

Also, make sure that there is a DNS entry for `mycoolwebsite.com` that points to your servers IP. This may be separate to the entry for `www.mycoolwebsite.com`.

Comment: Removed http:// from the first server block and still getting the error :(

Comment: Make sure to remove the trailing `/`, too. To diagnose a DNS problem, run `dig mycoolwebsite.com` and `dig www.mycoolwebsite.com` and see if both IPs point to the same server.

Comment: Thanks! So I did the `dig` and (www.mycoolwebsite.com) comes up with an IP address whereas (mycoolwebsite.com) comes up with ns1.digitalocean.com with no IP address?

Comment: You need to configure the DNS server (probably running at DigitalOcean) to return the right IP for mycoolwebsite.com. If it is DigitalOcean, this might help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean